# i always get -1 when I want to use outputStream to create file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I want to write some data into a text file, but I always get "Wrong" because the value for bytesWritten is -1. I have debugged that both the dataLength and dataBytes is ok and I think I have the permission to create file on desktop. What is the reason causes this and how can i fix it? the code is as follows:

```
void savedata(NSData *data)
{
    NSInteger       dataLength;
    const uint8_t * dataBytes;
    NSInteger       bytesWritten;
    NSInteger       bytesWrittenSoFar;
    dataLength = [data length];
    dataBytes  = [data bytes];

    NSOutputStream *fileStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"~/Desktop/12.txt" append:NO];

    bytesWrittenSoFar = 0;
    do {
        bytesWritten = [fileStream write:&dataBytes[bytesWrittenSoFar] maxLength:dataLength - bytesWrittenSoFar];
        assert(bytesWritten != 0);
        if (bytesWritten == -1) {
            NSLog(@"Wrong!");
            break;
        } else {
            bytesWrittenSoFar += bytesWritten;
        }
    } while (bytesWrittenSoFar != dataLength);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
NSData* data = [@"sadas" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

savedata(data);

return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must call `-open` on the stream before writing to it. If you read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOutputStream/outputStreamToFileAtPath%3aappend%3a) there is a little note:

> **Discussion**
>
> The stream must be opened before it can be used.

In the future, you can also get more information by querying the `-streamStatus` and `-streamError` methods when there is a problem.

Comment: I have added open. Now I can write into the path "/var/folders/mc/07b9zvv502sfz6m84tbtv18h0000gn/12.txt" but I can not write into "~/Desktop/12.txt"                                      //drwxr-xr-x   6 apple  staff   204  5  3 17:01 .  for the first path
    //drwx------+ 34 apple  staff      1156  5  3 15:27 . for the second path

Comment: I'm guessing you need to resolve the ~ yourself by using a method like `-stringByExpandingTildeInPath`